# How to handle user interaction wit flask app?

Tags: flask

I need some help getting the flask project layout right.

I have sth like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    ALL THE STUFF MY APP DOES - TASK1, TASK2, TASK3
    return render_template('result.html')
```

I get my app to do all the things I want: take user data, manipulate user data and return it to the user. I get this working when putting everything into one function, this was fine until now, when I try to get more user input I dont get it working.

When defining the tasks as different functions my app performs the upload and stops after that. I did the flask documentation Large Applications and Packages tutorial and I'm still where I was before that. The tutorial uses blueprints and has clearly separated tasks (blog posts, user handling). I dont want to store any data, just staying on the same page and have a sequence of user input, task, more user input, another task. I only get the first user input and task return done when I put everything into one function. No idea how to take more user input after that to perform more tasks.

I tried to define the separate tasks as functions with

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def task1():
```

and so on

Thanks for any input or referral to resources that I can look into.

see description above

Comment: you can't decorate every function with the same path. If each function is decorated with `@app.route('/')` I don't think the application will even run. It would also help to know that kind of data processing you're actually trying to do. Can you give an example of what task1, task2, and task3 might be?

Comment: oh good to know!

the user uploads an image. the app returns three images based on the user image. the user should select one of those and is asked for more input (text, images). the app returns another three images, the user selects one of those and so on. Does that make sense? I would like to keep everything on one path if possible. Or do I have to render a new template for each task?

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog and it clarified some misconceptions I had about structuring a flask app:

https://hackersandslackers.com/flask-application-factory/

As Peter recommended, I had to decorate different tasks with different routes.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    Upload file
    return redirect(url_for('TASK1'))

@app.route('/TASK1', methods=['GET', 'POST']
def TASK1():
    TASK1
    return render_template('TASK1.html')
```

and from there I can start again